# Excel formatting of numbers

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a large number in a text field (this field is a string) in *iReport*. It comes up to 20 numbers.
When this field gets exported to excel, it becomes 4.5656 E+. Is there any way I can make this number display as it is(4575758585995050857) in Excel by tweaking *iReport* textField so that it exports as it is?

Comment: I assume you mean you export to a text file and then import that to Excel.  With the Import Wizard, specify the column as type Text.

Comment: Actually the column type is text. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: right click on that column, then go to Properties then go to general and type 0(zero) 20 times.. u will see that column as 20 numbers...

Comment: I have just tried importing a text file and it works as I said. On the last window of the Import Wizard you can specify the type of each column. By default each column has a type of General but you can change it to, for example, Text. If you leave the type as General, Excel will notice that every character in a field is a digit and import it as a number. Excel cannot store numbers with twenty character precision so you lose some digits.

Comment: I am exporting to excel directly.

Comment: @Giri Can you post the snippet from jrxml file (with field definition, textField and queryExpression)?

Comment: <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
<reportElement
 x="0"
 y="0"
 width="237"  height="20" key="textField"/>
<textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ShopID}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>

Comment: @Giri And what about the field definition and queryString?

Comment: Alex- It is a string field and ShopID is the data from the DB

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714709/how-to-stop-excel-from-putting-numbers-like-this8-51100e10-from-jasper-reports

Answer (score 1):

I have created a text file with two 20-digit columns.  One I imported as Text and one I imported as General.  The images below show how I did it and the effect.

[image]

[image]

Not sure why Tab is still ticked.  I did not notice it at the time.

[image]

Notice I have changed the type of column 2 to Text.  Column 3 I have left as General.

[image]

[image]

Column 2 is text; column 3 is a number.

Comment: The question is not about settings in Excel, but about textField's format, expression or properties

Comment: @ Alex K. I do not use iReport so there may be more to the question than I appreciate. However, if you try importing the string "4575758585995050857" to Excel, it will be converted to a number unless you tell Excel not to.