# JasperReports: How to format numeric data with Excel exporter

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, number-formatting, ireport

I'm using *iReport 2.0.2*. 
I have a problem with formatting numeric data after generating report with help of Excel exporter.

For example, the `85110057689` string is showing as `8.51100e+10` in Excel file (as result of using "preview in Excel" button in *iReport*).

Please suggest how to change the format to the simple (not scientific).

Comment: I guess 85110057689 should be 8.51100e+10. Are you sure you didn't copy the wrong line?

Comment: im sorry,im mistakes put the example. i'll edit my question now

Comment: The problem now how to avoid the number 85110057689 to be 8.51100e+10 in excel when i publish the report.:(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type) property for solving issue.

The quote from documentation:

> **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type**
>
> Property whose value is used as default state of the IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE export flag.
>
> Specifies whether the exporter should take into consideration the type
>   of the original text field expressions and set the cell types and
>   values accordingly.

For example we can set this property for the whole report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ...>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

Comment: You are 100% correct about this. I added this to my project, and it did resolve the problem. Right on.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent large number displayed in scientific notation in Excel, make sure instead of value, you are putting ="value" in excel cell.

e.g. if numeric value = 85110057689, convert value in string format and format the result as '="85110057689"' where doublequotes wrap the big number and there is a '=' sign in front.

Comment: i have try in excel. it succes but this is not i want. What i want is when i publish the report,the number not to change format in excel. Which part that i can put the formula in iReports?

Comment: Specify FormatFactoryclass into report generation. Ref-->http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf